# How to declare a tweet as negative or neutral by using stanford NLP?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp, monkeylearn

I want to find the sentiment for

**@SouthwestAir Fastest response all day. Hour on the phone: never got off hold. Hour in line: never got to the Flight Booking Problems desk.**

When I use NLP sentiment class, I get

```
Neutral    @SouthwestAir Fastest response all day.
Negative    Hour on the phone: never got off hold.
Negative    Hour in line: never got to the Flight Booking Problems desk.
```

But when I use the Monkey Learn API for same text, I get a single sentiment

```
label : "negative"
```

How can I determine that the tweet text is negative using NLP sentiment class?

Comment: To clarify, is the concern here that CoreNLP splits the tweet into sentences and assigns sentiment on a sentence-by-sentence basis?

Answer (score 0):

CoreNLP scores each sentence.  If you replace each internal period (all but the last) with a semicolon or dash, I believe you'll get the effect you want.

```
@SouthwestAir Fastest response all day -- 
Hour on the phone: never got off hold -- 
Hour in line: never got to the Flight Booking Problems desk.
```

Comment: Disclaimers, however: this will (1) be rather slow (parsing is O(n^3)), and (2) will likely confuse the parser, and therefore the RNN sentiment analyzer. Hopefully not by much, but that's an empirical question.